# Espresso count elements

Tags: android, android-espresso

Is there a way to count elements with a certain id in Espresso?

I can do `onView(withId(R.id.my_id))` but then I'm stuck.

I have a LinearLayout where I inject elements (not a ListView), and I want to test how many or those are to check whether they match expected behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the matcher that I came up with:

```
public static Matcher<View> withViewCount(final Matcher<View> viewMatcher, final int expectedCount) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            int actualCount = -1;

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                if (actualCount >= 0) {
                    description.appendText("With expected number of items: " + expectedCount);
                    description.appendText("\n With matcher: ");
                    viewMatcher.describeTo(description);
                    description.appendText("\n But got: " + actualCount);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(View root) {
                actualCount = 0;
                Iterable<View> iterable = TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(root);
                actualCount = Iterables.size(Iterables.filter(iterable, withMatcherPredicate(viewMatcher)));
                return actualCount == expectedCount;
            }
        };
    }

    private static Predicate<View> withMatcherPredicate(final Matcher<View> matcher) {
        return new Predicate<View>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(@Nullable View view) {
                return matcher.matches(view);
            }
        };
    }
```

and the usage is:

```
onView(isRoot()).check(matches(withViewCount(withId(R.id.anything), 5)));
```

Comment: I'm having an issue with the Iterables after upgrading to Espresso 3.0.0. The import changed from android.support.test.espresso.core.deps.guava.collect.Iterables; to android.support.test.espresso.core.internal.deps.guava.collect.Iterables; and in doing so, lost the .size necessary for this code.

Comment: How about using `Iterables.filter(iterable, withMatcherPredicate(viewMatcher)).count()` instead ?

Comment: Ended up using size anyway with this: `= Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(iterable, withMatcherPredicate(viewMatcher))).size`

Also hello from 2020!

Answer (score 2):

There is and Kotlin version of the [Be_Negative](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879701/be-negative)'s answer:

declaration:

```
fun withViewCount(viewMatcher: Matcher<View>, expectedCount: Int): Matcher<View?> {
return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View?>() {
    private var actualCount = -1
    override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        when {
            actualCount >= 0 -> description.also {
                it.appendText("Expected items count: $expectedCount, but got: $actualCount")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(root: View?): Boolean {
        actualCount = TreeIterables.breadthFirstViewTraversal(root).count {
            viewMatcher.matches(it)
        }
        return expectedCount == actualCount
    }
}
```

}

Usage in test, for example, checking RadioButtons count in a RadioGroup:

```
 onView(withId(R.id.radioGroup)).check(
     matches(
         withViewCount(instanceOf(RadioButton::class.java), 3)
     )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a custom matcher. You can define one in Kotlin in the next way:

```
fun withChildViewCount(count: Int, childMatcher: Matcher<View>): Matcher<View> {

    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, ViewGroup>(ViewGroup::class.java) {
        override fun matchesSafely(viewGroup: ViewGroup): Boolean {
            val matchCount = viewGroup.children
                    .filter { childMatcher.matches(it) }
                    .count()
            return matchCount == count
        }

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("with child count $count")
        }

    }
}
```