# Counting number of text views within a framelayout

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am new to espresso UI testing and trying to count the number of text views displays in a particular screen in the app. I tried something like the following

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.listview),
    isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.framelayout))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches (Matchers.withListSize (2)))))
```

with the following custom matcher

```
class Matchers {
  public static Matcher<View> withListSize (final int size) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View> () {
      @Override public boolean matchesSafely (final View view) {
        return ((ListView) view).getCount () == size;
      }

      @Override public void describeTo (final Description description) {
        description.appendText ("ListView should have " + size + " items");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I tried the one mentioned here, [Espresso count elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349395/espresso-count-elements) doesn't work with the latest version.